# My Discord bot is having trouble with an error that is stating that there is something wrong with my token

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, discord

So,everytime i try to execute my bot by doing node . it works normally and then i get this error

```
D:\MovedFilesRZHDTP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:237
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
                                                   ^

Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (D:\MovedFilesRZHDTP\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:237:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MovedFilesRZHDTP\Desktop\DiscordBot\Bot.js:90:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'
}
```

I also checked to see if my token is incorrect by regenerating a new one but it gives the same error

the "error" is coming from here

```
 async login(token = this.token) {
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
    this.token = token = token.replace(/^(Bot|Bearer)\s*/i, '');
    this.emit(
      Events.DEBUG,
      `Provided token: ${token
        .split('.')
        .map((val, i) => (i > 1 ? val.replace(/./g, '*') : val))
        .join('.')}`,
    );
```

Comment: How are we supposed to debug, if you don't provide the code?

Comment: if is throwing at that first line in the function. So `this.token` is either undefined or not a string. If you showed more of the `this` object and how that object is instantiated we might be able to help more.